# Feeding only images in Chainer model

Tags: image-processing, dataset, chainer

I have a dataset containing only images which will be used in an autoencoder to regenerate the input images. I want to use chainer ImageDataset to feed the data into iterator.

```
data = test_tup = chainer.datasets.ImageDataset('/NewText.txt', '/train')
```

I have given the address of text file containing address of images and in the root the address of the folder where the images are kept.

```
 79         _check_pillow_availability()
 80         if isinstance(paths, six.string_types):
---> 81             with open(paths) as paths_file:
 82                 paths = [path.strip() for path in paths_file]
 83         self._paths = paths

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/NewText.txt'
```

Is this the correct way to use ImageDataset? Also I want to know whether ImageDataset is a good option for feeding in only images or is there any other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the path is probably different from what you expect. `print(paths)` may help identify the issue.

datasets.LabeledImageDataset() may be better. For an example of the import, look here: https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/v5.4.0/examples/imagenet/train_imagenet.py

Hope that helps,

Comment: Hi Crissman Loomis..started learning chainer with your video 5 months back. Coming to point..my dataset is for unsupervised learning consisting of only images, no labels.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Then yes, ImageDataset seems appropriate. Hopefully a path issue.